# Split an arbitrary array into segments of two kinds

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, segment

Let's say I have an arbitrary integer array filled with zeros and positive numbers.
Need to split these arrays into solid and dashed indexed segments following left rule.

```
let array1 = [0, 0, 14, 54, 23, 0, 34, 11, 12, 54];

let array2 = [14, 0, 43, 13, 0, 0, 54, 0];
```

[image]

So the considerable output for `array1` have to be

```
let out = {solid: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], dashed: [[0, 1], [4, 5]]};
```

and for `array2`

```
let out = {solid: [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6]], dashed: [[0, 1], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]}
```

In other words, I need a solution for going through an array and split it into segments. If the right value of `i + 1` is `0`, then the segment or part of the segment must be considered as dashed, if any `positive integer`-solid. The segments could be of any length as long as values satisfy the condition.

Comment: In the second example, shouldn't 0-1 be dashed and 1-3 solid?

Comment: yeah, you're right, fixed.

Comment: So what JavaScript have you used and need help with? Post it as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this covers every scenario but you could try something like this using a `for` and a `while` loops and finding a occurrences where the current elements is 0 and the next element is not, and then from that point you search for zeros backwards and not zeros forwards.

```js
let array1 = [0, 0, 14, 54, 23, 0, 34, 11, 12, 54];
let array2 = [14, 0, 43, 13, 0, 0, 54, 0];

function parse(data) {
  const dashed = []
  const solid = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const current = data[i],
      next = data[i + 1]

    if (current === 0 && next !== 0) {
      let ineg = i,
        ipos = i,
        arrneg = [i],
        arrpos = [i]

      while (data[ineg--] === 0 && ineg > -1) {
        arrneg.unshift(ineg)
      }

      while (data[++ipos] !== 0 && ipos < data.length) {
        arrpos.push(ipos)
      }

      if (arrneg.length > 1) dashed.push(arrneg)
      if (arrpos.length > 1) solid.push(arrpos)
    }
  }

  return {
    solid,
    dashed
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(array1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(array2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

My version. Still no so elegant as it could be.

```js
let array1 = [0, 0, 14, 54, 23, 0, 34, 11, 12, 54];
let array2 = [14, 0, 43, 13, 0, 0, 54, 0];

function myparse(data){

  let pairs = [], dashed = [], solid = [];
  const mapped = (pair) => { return Array.from({length: pair.i1 - pair.i0 + 1 }, (_, i_) => { return pair.i0++; }); }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++){ pairs.push({i0: i, i1: (i + 1), type: data[i + 1] !== 0 ? 'solid' : 'dashed' }); }

  let pair = pairs[0];
    
  for(let i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++){
  
    if(pairs[i].type !== pair.type){
       if(pair.type === 'solid') { solid.push(mapped(pair)); }
       else{ dashed.push(mapped(pair));  }
       pair = pairs[i];
    }
    else{
       pair.i1 = pairs[i].i1;
    }
  }

  pair.type === 'dashed' ? dashed.push(mapped(pair)) : solid.push(mapped(pair));
  
  return { 
    dashed, 
    solid 
  }
  
}

console.log(myparse(array1));
console.log(myparse(array2));
```